# What is more performant, a single Deck instance or multiple per map?

Tags: deck.gl

I am using DeckGL with react, and i had a question about best practices considering the amount of Deck instances. One option is to add all layers in a single Deck instance, for example:

```
<DeckGL layers={[layerA, layerB, layerC, layerD]} />
```

Or to split them between diffrent instances, for example:

```
<DeckGL layers={[layerA, layerB]} />
<DeckGL layers={[layerC, layerD]} />
```

The second approach lets you incapsulate diffrent deck instances:

```
const RegionsLayer = () => <DeckGL layers={[layerA, layerB]} />;
const WeatherLayer = () => <DeckGL layers={[layerC, layerD]} />;
```

does one approach have a performance advantage compared to the other?

I did both approaches, in basic usage both work well.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the answer i got from ibgreen in the deck gl repository discussion.

"There are no practical advantages to having two DeckGL instances other than if you absolutely need to draw into two separate canvases. Not that deck.gl has a view system to let you draw multiple views into a single canvas.

You'll avoid duplicated overhead with a single deck.gl instance (= single WebGL context), both in terms of GPU and CPU memory as well as browser resources. Things like offscreen GPU buffers for picking etc add to that overhead.

The performance and memory savings of using two views in a single deck instance become more significant if you share layers between the two instances. Less pronounced if each instance shows independent data and layers..

Also be aware that browsers have a limited number of WebGL contexts, so there is a fairly small limit to how many Deck instances you can have."